# Какие марки браузеров поддерживают приложения XBAP?

Tags: wpf

Из каких браузеров я смогу воспользоваться своим приложением XBAP на сегодняшний день?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Internet Explorer 6 или выше
- Mozilla Firefox 2 или выше
- Google Chrome и Opera (открывает через мозиловские dll)

[WPF browser applications (XBAP) in Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Maxthon.](https://supersuperclass.appspot.com/xbap-in-browsers.html)

Comment: Вы забыли упомянуть - только на винде.